# iPad "dismiss keyboard" button (lower right), how do I detect when this occurs? What function tells me it was pressed?

Tags: xcode, ipad, keyboard, uitextfield

I have an ipad app that when you are in landscape view, the view will move up when the keyboard is brought in. When you press done on the keyboard, textFieldShouldReturn and textFieldShouldEndEditing are called in which case, I move the view down in shouldEndEditing.

If the user presses the dismiss keyboard button, the keyboard does poof, yet the view is still stuck floating where I moved it.

I need to know how or what function is called when that button is pressed so I can redirect the function to textFieldShouldEndEditing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can listen for keyboard hide **UIKeyboardWillHideNotification** notification.

Example code is here http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/KeyboardAccessory/Listings/Classes_ViewController_m.html

Comment: I was able to use that to detect when the keyboard left. By putting the textfield should return code in the keyboard hide code, it called it either way. Then it would call textfielddidendediting code. Thanks!

Comment: I'm fairly certain this notification is simply a result of the textfield losing first responder status. Is there a way to detect the actual tap event on the button, so we can circumvent losing first responder status and perform a different action?

Comment: This doesn't fire for me when the hide keyboard button is pressed. Hiding the keyboard keeps the undo/redo buttons visible at the bottom of the screen, only when you dismiss them does it fire. iPad Pro on iOS 12.1.

Answer (score 13):

When the "lower keyboard" button is pressed, the textfield delegate method of:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

Won't be called.

When either the "lower keyboard" or "return button" are pressed, the:

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

Will be called.

I use a variable `NSString *lowerKeyboardButtonPressed` initially set to `@""` which I set to `@"N"` in the `textfieldShouldReturn` method ... then in the `textFieldDidEndEditing` method I check to see if it is set to `@"N"` ... then I know if the return key or lower keyboard key was pressed. The last line in my `textFieldDidEndEditing` method sets the variable back to `@""`.

Comment: The return button will only fire textFieldDidEndEditing if you implement textFieldShouldReturn and resignFirstResponder inside that method.

Comment: I've found the above answer(s) to be much more useful ... using a "UIKeyboardWillHideNotification" is the key!!!

Comment: "I use a variable NSString *lowerKeyboardButtonPressed ..."   -- you should use a BOOL variable for this.

Comment: Using Keyboard Notifications is the best solution no doubt! Check the accepted answer for this thread. :)

Comment: textFieldDidEndEditing is *not* called for the "lower keyboard" button.

Comment: @nate, perhaps it doesn't fire anymore ... answer was from 2012

Answer (score 2):

If you press the keyboard dismiss button and you have a hardware keyboard attached, then the `willHide` will only be called if you don't have an input accessory view.  At which point you need to adjust in the `willShow` as well (which will have a negative difference between the `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` and `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` keys).